# Perform serial work in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have Google AppEngine application which fetch data from multiple sources and then I want to process all the data in serial manner.

What is the best way to do it?

Ido

Comment: In a serial manner? So you _don't_ want any parallelism?

Comment: exactly. Because I process messages that affect the same data I want to process them serially so message 1 will affect the data before message 2 and message 2 will be affected by message 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach: store the fetched data in the datastore. Use [TaskQueues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) to process the data.